Authorize.net with woocomerce capture shipping cost later
I'm using Authorize.net payment gateway with Woocommerce (Wordpress). We are getting customers pre authorized for order value and we want to add shipping cost and tax amounts later on.
WooCommerce Authorize.Net Gateway (Enterprise) is the plugin we are using.
https://pledgedplugins.com/products/authorize-net-payment-gateway-woocommerce/
When I add shipping cost to order from woocommerce default option and update order status to "Processing" it does not capture because order value is different from what was pre authorized because of the added shipping cost.
Is there any possible way to achieve this?
Thank you

think you're going to need custom code to handle this. we're in similar situation.
